# Resharper 5 vs 6

Tags: resharper, syntax-highlighting, resharper-5.0, resharper-5.x, resharper-6.0

Back when I had ReSharper 5 my files would have all kinds of syntax highlighting and a bar next to the scrollbar to the right. It was wonderful because it would highlight redundant imports and possible code smells, as well mark things in the bar next to the scroll bar.

With ReSharper 6 I don't have any of that. I have to actually have cursor on what I want to change and wait for the pencil or light bulb to show up. Is this how ReSharper 6 is by default or do I have to reinstall it?

Comment: Looks like your settings got messed up. Try re-installing.

Answer (score 2):

First make sure ReSharper is acutally activated. If it is, there should be a ReSharper top level menu entry in Visual Studio at the top.

If it is, make sure "Enable Code Analysis" is turned on in the ReSharper settings.

If it is not, enable ReSharper in the Visual Studio settings (Tools->Options). There should be an extra entry "ReSharper" in the list on the left side. Click the "Resume" button.

If you don't have such an entry in your Visual Studio settings, ReSharper is either not or not correctly installed.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the settings were not taken from the version 5 folder to the version 6 one. Try the following:

- Make sure you close Visual Studio.
- Go to:

**Note**: this folder is from a Windows 7 machine, since you didn't provide information on which version of visual studio you are using I'm putting 'x'

"c:\Users*your user*\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\ReSharper\v5.x\vsxx.x"

In there you'll find a UserSettings.xml file open it for edit.

- Look for the "SeverityTable" node. Select it and copy it.
- Paste it on the same file that you'll find on the "c:\Users*your user*\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\Resharper\v6.0\vsxx.x" folder. I recommend making a backup of the file before doing that.
- Reopen visual studio. Resharper should be indicating all the recommendations and smells as it did before you updated it.

Hope this helps.